# Get scroll bar in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I would like to create scroll bar on my data in JavaScript. I'm getting data from JSON, like so:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
try {
var abc = json.abc;
 for ( var i = 0; i < abc .length; i++) {
   abcHtml = abcHtml + abc [i].value + "<br/>";
  }
```

To apply scroll bar, I used `overflow:scroll;`

But it displays a normal popup menu, not a scroll bar. But whenever I open Firebug tab or move Firebug tab then I get scroll bar of list in popup menu.

Comment: You need to describe your problem in more detail. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by you get a normal popup menu.

Is abcHtml a div?

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
container.style.height = '300px';

...
{   var abc = json.abc;
    var out = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
        out += abc[i].value + "<br/>";
    }
    container.innerHTML = out;
}
```

That would give you a div that scrolls after the contents are of size > than 300px